# Is there away to know who has published several high quality papers in a specific academic field/area during the last 5 years for example

Tags: publications, peer-review, publishers, publishability

I am trying to submit a paper for publication. The journal is asking to provide a list of experts who have published several high quality papers in the field of interest. Is there away to find this out easily?

Comment: Who are the authors of the papers that you cited in your paper?

Comment: Would you please clarify "area"?  Do you mean geographic area or academic area?

Comment: I mean an academic area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe easiest way I can think of is to access Elsevier's platform called http://www.scopus.com . There, you can do paper research based on author's name, field, date and nº of citations. Take the top citated works and research their impact factor on google scholar.

Comment: This is the wrong notion of 'field of interest' - for the question's purposes, you want a list of experts in Underwater Basketweaving in New England Estuaries, not a list of experts in Basketweaving.

Comment: Such purpose wasn't specified in the question. Regardless, it really depends on how the person is going to conduct his/her bibliographic research. He/she can research the keyword "Basketweaving" AND "New England" (treating the latter as another keyword) in order to specify his results for a certain region. It is also possible to cross a keyword search with a title search and, considering that usually articles' titles contain the region the study was developed, this approach might give him a decent a starting point.

Comment: @Eric Lino, the website you shared with use is  very useful and helped me a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that Scopus is not free -- if your university has not paid big money to Elsevier, you can't access it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Google Scholar to look up papers on the topic of interest, then look at (a) the papers they cite, (b) the papers that cite them (Google Scholar can give you a list). Keep following the links until you run out of interesting papers, then look to see which authors keep appearing.
2. Look at the major conferences/journals in your field to get a list of potentially-relevant papers, then look to see which authors keep appearing.

The union of the results of these two approaches will generally get you close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, I've used Scopus website and I got what I was looking for. I advise others to use the same approach if they are looking for the same thing.